# Set windowTranslucentStatus=true when android lollipop or higher

Tags: java, android, api, android-5.0-lollipop

I'd like to set windowTranslucentStatus to true when the user is on lollipop and above because otherwise (at least on kitkat) the app bar appears inside the system bar. On lollipop it is fine. Without making separate styles.xml for each version which apparently you shouldn't have to do anymore how can I set it in java?

I have the following code in my mainActivity but don't know hot windowTranslucentStatus... Any ideas?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    // set windowTranslucentStatus = true
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
```

Comment: I've used that at the top of my onCreate method and also tried after setContentView but doesn't seem to make any difference. System print out confirms that the code is being run but it looks the same with or without the code.

Comment: I have edited my answer, I checked its working now, please check.

Comment: is there a way to programmatically toggle the status bar to appear again

Answer (score 9):

You can switch between translucent or not whenever you want using this :

```
public static void setTranslucent(Activity activity, boolean translucent){
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  Window w = activity.getWindow();
  if(translucent) {
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
  }
  else{
    w.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
  }
}
```